# "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type" with bsb react template

Tags: webpack, reason, webpack-4, bucklescript

I have a file `View.js`, that contains a stateless component:

```
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import React from 'react';

const View = (props) => ( 
  <div>
    <Button variant="raised" >
      {props.name}
    </Button>
  </div>
);

export default View;
```

Then I wrote a wrapper `ViewWrapper.re`, to interoperate with reasonml

```
[@bs.module] external viewJS : ReasonReact.reactClass = "./View";

let make = (~name: string, children) =>
  ReasonReact.wrapJsForReason(
    ~reactClass=viewJS,
    ~props={"name": name },
    children
  );
```

Then add the wrapper into `index.re`

```
ReactDOMRe.renderToElementWithId(<Component1 message="Hello!" />, "index1");
ReactDOMRe.renderToElementWithId(<Component2 greeting="Hello!" />, "index2");
ReactDOMRe.renderToElementWithId(<ViewWrapper name="Material" />, "index2");
```

the compiler complains:

```
ERROR in ./src/View.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
| const View = (props) => (
|   <div>
|     <Button variant="raised" >
|       {props.name}
 @ ./src/ViewWrapper.bs.js 4:11-28
 @ ./src/Index.bs.js
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update** . 
I created my reason project with

```
bsb -init my-react-app -theme react
```

command.
And I added View.js to project:
[image]

The `bsconfig.js` looks as following:

```
/* This is the BuckleScript configuration file. Note that this is a comment;
  BuckleScript comes with a JSON parser that supports comments and trailing
  comma. If this screws with your editor highlighting, please tell us by filing
  an issue! */
{
  "name": "react-template",
  "reason": {
    "react-jsx": 2
  },
  "sources": {
    "dir" : "src",
    "subdirs" : true
  },
  "package-specs": [{
    "module": "commonjs",
    "in-source": true
  }],
  "suffix": ".bs.js",
  "namespace": true,
  "bs-dependencies": [
    "reason-react"
  ],
  "refmt": 3,
  "warnings": {
    "error": "+5"
  }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you using reason-scripts? This isn't the compiler complaining. Seems like a bundler. Probably becasue you're mixing different module formats. What's bucklescript configured to output, and what format does the bundler expect?

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: What is the different between `bsb -init my-react-app -theme react` and `yarn create react-app my-app --scripts-version reason-scripts`?

Comment: `reason-scripts` is a buggy pile of complexity that tries to pretend it's simple by hiding all the complexity so you have no idea what's going on. `bsb -init` on the other hand gives you a very simple but barebones setup that is easy to understand and add to. IMO, under no circumstance should you use `reason-scripts`. But the reason I asked is because `reason-scripts` conflates the compilcation and bundling process, so it might seem like they're one and the same. `bsb -init` on the other hand uses separate commands for compilation and bundling

Comment: Your `bsconfig.json` is set up to output commonjs modules, and your `View.js` is es6. So you're mixing module types, which isn't a very good idea. I'd recommend you either convert `View.js` to commonjs, or configure bucklescript and webpack to output and bundle es6.

Comment: `configure bucklescript and webpack` how can I do it?

Comment: I don't know about webpack. Maybe you don't have to do anything. BuckleScript docs are here: https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/build-configuration.html#package-specs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168068/discussion-between-zero-coding-and-glennsl).

Comment: I changed in the bsconfig file `"module": "es6"` and still I've got `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

Comment: Then maybe you need babel-loader for es6? I'm really not sure. I've only used rollup for es6 bundling.

Comment: Oh, it's probably because it's JSX, not because it's es6. So you probably need to set up babel-loader with a jsx transform. Pretty much a standard react setup I would guess.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the use of (JavaScript) JSX. You'll need to set up Babel with an ES6/JSX transform to output plain JavaScript, as Glenn said.

The easiest way to do this is to set your project up as a normal ReactJS project (create-react-app, etc.) and add a `bsconfig.json` file (you can reuse the one you have now). Turning an existing ReactJS project into a ReasonReact project is actually pretty simple–once you have the `bsconfig.json` file and the right dependencies in `package.json`, you're pretty much set.